# Use iterm2 to display Chinese/Utf8

Tags: terminal, iterm, utf-8

How to make iterm2 to properly display Chinese/Utf8?

Say I want to execute these commands under iterm2:

```
touch Hello世界.txt
touch Hello老师我想你.mp3
touch Hello❤️.txt
```

and this is what I'm getting now:

[image]

Note that

- The [Terminal app](https://support.apple.com/lt-lt/guide/terminal/trml15220/mac) works out of the box for me without any of my tweaking:
  [image]
- The created Hello世界.txt file name show up in my file finder just properly. It is iterm2 that's causing all these problems:

  [image]

This the setting I'm using based on the following searches:

[image]

- https://logs.paulooi.com/how-to-view-chinese-character-with-iterm-in-mac-osx.php
- https://iterm2.com/3.3/documentation-preferences-profiles-text.html
- https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/pages/tanfbd4156e/mac
- https://www.help.k12.com/s/article/Viewing-Chinese-Characters-on-a-Mac
- https://chinesemac.org/pages/fonts.html

Comment: Do either of those fonts you have selected have the glyphs you are asking for?

Comment: This is not the glyphs' problem @MarcWilson -- the file names show up in my file finder just properly. It is iterm2 that's causing such problems. OP updated.